# Change ImagePlus image Color

Tags: imagej

I am trying to change image color of type imagePlus but i am not able to do so.
Below ist he code for that, image is black and White

```
ImagePlus t= IJ.openImage("image.tif");
    ImageStack c = new ImageStack(t.getWidth(), t.getHeight());
    c.addSlice(t.getStack().getProcessor(1));
    ImagePlus ss = new ImagePlus("sss",c);
    ss.show();
    ss.getProcessor().convertToRGB().setOverColor(0, 255, 0);
    ss.updateAndDraw();
```

Answer (score 2):

As I wrote in the answer to [your question on the ImageJ forum](http://forum.imagej.net/t/how-can-i-change-a-color-of-an-image-programmatically/6416?u=imagejan), you can use the `CompositeImage#setLuts(LUT[] luts)` method. Here's an illustrative Groovy script:

```groovy
#@ ImagePlus imp

import ij.process.LUT
import java.awt.Color
import ij.CompositeImage

if (imp instanceof CompositeImage) {
    luts = imp.getLuts()
    luts[0] = LUT.createLutFromColor(Color.CYAN)
    luts[1] = LUT.createLutFromColor(Color.MAGENTA)
    imp.setLuts(luts)
    imp.updateAndDraw() 
}
```

Comment: Thanks i will check this and get back to you.

Comment: Hi @Jan Eglinger, how can i convert imageplus image to Composite image?